# ph error : notice : undefined variable : id in c:\wamp how to fix it?? $_SESSION error

Tags: php, android, mysql, undefined, session-variables

i am creating android application that need connection with php mysql  the application work perfect in the android side.

the problem is in the php file  when i am trying to store $_SESSION for id from file to file to file the php display an error :
 **Undefined variable id in c:\wamp\www\android_connect\status.php on line 53**

how can i fix this error i will post the three file of php that contain

- register
- login
- status

## register.php

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();
if(empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
       $response["success"] = 0;
       $response["message"] = "enter Both Fields";
        // echoing JSON response
        die (json_encode($response));


}

// check for required fields
else if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password']) ) {

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    //check if the user exist !!!!
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '$user'");

    $count_query = mysql_num_rows($check);
    if($count_query > 0){
       $response["success"] = 0;
       $response["message"] = "User Already Exist!!";
        // echoing JSON response
        die (json_encode($response));
    }else if(strlen($user)<6){

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Your user Name Must bigger than 6 Char.";
        // echoing JSON response
        die (json_encode($response));     
    }else if(strlen($password)<8){

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Your Password Must bigger than 8 Char.";
        // echoing JSON response
        die (json_encode($response));     
    }else{

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(user, password) VALUES('$user', '$password')");

      //**************************
      //added  and can be deleted 
      //*************************
      $id = mysql_insert_id();

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database

        //**************************
        //added  and can be deleted 
        //*************************
        $_SESSION['id'] = mysql_insert_id();

        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "User successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        die (json_encode($response));
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        die (json_encode($response));
    }
  }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
        die (json_encode($response));
}
?>
```

## login.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
@session_start();

//array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if(empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
       $response["success"] = 0;
       $response["message"] = "enter Both Fields";
        // echoing JSON response
        die (json_encode($response));


}

else if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password']) ) {

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    // include db connect class
    require_once '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $sql = mysql_query("Select * from users where user='$user' and password = '$password'")or die(mysql_error());
    $count_query = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    if($count_query >0){
    //*******************************
    //added can be deleted
    //*******************************


    $user_details = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
     $response["success"] = 1;

     $id = $user_details['id'];
     $_SESSION['id'] = $id; 



    $response['id'] = $user_details['id'];
     $response["message"] = "correct Informations";

   // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
     else{
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Wrong User Or Pass";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

## status.php

```
        <?php ob_start(); 
//array for JSON response 
$response = array();

           if(!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start();


           }

           if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {

              $id= $_SESSION['id'];

           } 

           //var_dump ($id);

           // include db connect class
               require_once '/db_connect.php';

               // connecting to db
               $db = new DB_CONNECT();

           // check for required fields
              if(empty($_POST['status'])){
               $response["success"] = 0;
               $response["message"] = "Your Text Field is empty";
                // echoing JSON response
                   die (json_encode($response));


           } else if (isset($_POST['status'])) {

               $status = $_POST['status'];
                        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO status (status_text, uid)VALUES('$status', '$id')")or die(mysql_error());

                  if ($sql) {
                   // successfully inserted into database

                $response["success"] = 1;
                   $response["message"] = "Status Saved.";

                   // echoing JSON response
                   die (json_encode($response));
               } else {
                   // failed to insert row
                   $response["success"] = 0;
                   $response["message"] = "Error in saving the status.";

                   // echoing JSON response
                   die (json_encode($response));
               }
                }

           ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

i know that the error is in the insert query but i do not know why it do not assign the sesion id to the variable $id.

Comment: you never started the session in register.php, and why are u sppressing errors on session_start in login.php?

Comment: @ Bryan in the register.php  i start the session by adding $_SESSION['id'] = mysql_insert_id();       and in the login i suppressing the session_start because it was give an error    is this wrong what i did ??

Comment: you need `session_start()` to be the first line on all the files. Also the error you were getting is probably part of the problem.

Comment: ok i will edit my file and try it hope that will fix the problem

Comment: i added  session_start() to the register.php  and login.php and in the status.php i add the session_start() to the first line of my file but still give the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the Session in status.php first, I'm pretty sure in register.php you need to do the same thing.

Comment: ok i will edit my file and try it hope that will fix the problem